# Jquery * Selector Query

Tags: jquery

I know this might sound simple but somehow I am not able to understand the logic behind following piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert("Dom Length:"+$('*').length);
            var a = "hi";
            alert($.type(a));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting output as Dom Length:5 but I am not understanding how the lenght is populated.

**UPDATE1:**

I alerady had idea that it will select all elements in DOM, counting was misleading me. One more addition to this what if I add `<p> hi </p>` in body; it still shows length as 5. Is it right or should it be 6?

Comment: "UPDATE1" ? You know you're not supposed to add questions after you've been correctly answered ? I hope there won't be an "UPDATE2"...

Comment: Should I post another question?

Comment: For the update1 ? I don't think so as I answered. But please refrain to add other sequels (you still may ask for precision if the answers aren't clear).

Comment: ok. I have added a <p>hi</p> not just hi; as per you said $('*').get().map(function(e){ return e.tagName }) ; this is returning 6 but I am only getting 5 in an alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('*')` use the [all-selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) and you have 5 elements in your page :

1. html
2. head
3. script
4. body
5. script

I suggest you run this in the console :

```
$('*').get().map(function(e){ return e.tagName })
```

---

EDIT for your second question :

Adding `hi` in the body wouldn't add an *element* but a *text node*, that's why the count wouldn't change. Read [more about nodes and elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node).

---

EDIT for your comment :

Note that the script doesn't see the elements that are after itself. If you want it to see the whole DOM, change it to

```
$(function(){
    alert("Dom Length:"+$('*').length);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, you have these tags :

- 1 `<html>`
- 1 `<head>`
- 1 `<body>`
- 2 `<script>`

So `1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 5`.

Answer (score 1):

**`'*'`** represesnt all in jQuery, so when we say `$('*')` it means all DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically selecting all elements of an HTML.

In this case you have total 5 elements.

Indeed, it is a simple question. However, you are not alone.

I have been facing same issue but things answered easily by using reference card.

you can get one from the following link:

http://marieraney.com/webclass/docs/jquery_selectors_refcard.pdf

Comment: *"all valid elements, opening & closing"*. What does that exactly mean ?